# Is Eren's Titan in "rage/flame" mode stronger?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In [episode 25, when Eren is fighting Annie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-QxK1I7Va8), he is seen in what is called "rage/flame" mode (this name is given by fans I believe, though not sure).

[image: Eren's flaming titan]

Is he supposed to be stronger when he's like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ShingekiNoKyojin subreddit, fans have referred to this as "berserk" mode. What is important for any anime-only watcher of the series to know is that berserk mode, or flame mode, isn't present in the Shingeki no Kyojin manga.

This means that berserk mode has no relevance to events further down in the story for the manga. This may change in the anime, and berserk mode may be an important plot point, but I think it's far more likely that Eren will not enter berserk mode again in the series. I think it was just the animators adding a little bit of filler to the Annie fight.

To answer your question, is flame mode stronger? Yeah probably a little. If anything it was a visual notifier to the audience that Eren had a second wind and increased motivation to take Annie out, thus making him "stronger" in a sense.

Answer (score -1):

I personally believe that the berserker mode is just Eren tapping into the founding titans abilities, resulting in the whole flame thing, so yes it would be stronger.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. Could you expand the answer by [edit]ing it and explaining the reason? While personal theory is an acceptable answer, it'd be better if it could be backed up by some sources/references to make it more convincing. Meanwhile, consider taking a quick [tour] to understand how this site works, and enjoy~

Answer (score -2):

Eren's Berserk Titan form is an increased amount of rage forming in side him wanting to break out, but can only be accssesed in his tian form because if he was a human the power would kill him. The berserk titan is like super saiyan in some other terms they both require rage and they both increase power and they both create a monster that is all I have time for

Comment: This seems like nothing more than personal opinion, and has no foundation with half of the claims you make here. It honestly just feels like Headcanon compared to the other answer.

Comment: True but if you  think about it the berserk titan is just a power booster for the attack titan achieved by extreme anger

Comment: From what I saw and read, the Attack titan seems to be the strongest titan excluding the Colossal for obvious reasons. So any feat of strength it demonstrates that is greater than the others is to be expected and is normal. Him seeming stronger is more likely him just being serious and reckless in his attacks, combined with him compensating for the damage  its suffered. Annie is also not trying to win but run away, so she is at a distinct disadvantage, meaning we don't have an accurate comparison between normal and berserk mode to say if he was actually stronger or not.